# Get info from database in grails

Tags: grails

Im newbie in Grails and now Im trying get one parametr from database. So I have domain class:

```
class Category {

    String category
    String description

    static mapping = {
        table 'categorydescription'
        category column: 'category'
        description column: 'description'
        version false
        cache true
    }
}
```

and want see "description" on index page, how can I do that?
I tried

```
def index = {
        List<Category> сategoryInfo = Category.list()

        renderIndex(   
                сategoryInfo
        )
    }
```

and in view

```
<g:each in="${categoryInfo}" var="p">

    <li>${p.description}</li>
</g:each>
```

but see nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is that method renderIndex

```
renderIndex(   
            сategoryInfo
    )
```

you just need to pass the model. Replace that method call with **[сategoryInfo:сategoryInfo]**

Comment: do it and see nothing(

Comment: have  you created any of the categories, before checking result

Comment: log say to me that object in controller... List<Category> сategoryInfo = Category.list() working

Comment: But does it have size great than 1..? If you haven't created any Category before then of-course rendered page will be blank

Comment: You must be new to Grails. I recommend you to go through some Quick Start Tutorials. (http://www.vogella.com/articles/Grails/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Lookup the docs on querying [Querying with GORM](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#querying). That should tell you all you need to see the value of `description` on the index page

Comment: ideally do that through a controller. it would be instructive to generate-all the scaffolding for your domain and read the code that it generates `generate-all Category` at the command line